# Go: Skip bytes from a stream using io.reader

Tags: go

What is the best way in Go to skip forward a number of bytes in a stream using `io.Reader`?  That is, is there a function in the standard library which takes a *reader* and a *count* that will read and dispose *count* bytes from the *reader*?

Example use case:

```
func DoWithReader(r io.Reader) {      
    SkipNBytes(r, 30);     // Read and dispose 30 bytes from reader
}
```

I don't need to go backwards in the stream so anything that can work without converting `io.Reader` to another reader type would be preferred.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use this construction:

```
import "io"

io.CopyN(io.Discard, yourReader, count)
```

It copies the requested amount of bytes into an `io.Writer` that discards what it reads.

If your `io.Reader` is an `io.Seeker`, you might want to consider seeking in the stream to skip the amount of bytes you want to skip:

```
import "io"

switch r := yourReader.(type) {
case io.Seeker:
    r.Seek(count, io.SeekCurrent)
default:
    io.CopyN(io.Discard, r, count)
}
```

Comment: Package ioutil has been deprecated as of go1.19. Use io.Discard instead.